# Bitrise.io scheme not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcodebuild, bitrise

For some reason I'm getting an error message on Bitrise.io saying the scheme cannot be found within the project. It says to use the -list command, however doing that locally finds the scheme fine.

I know a common reason for this problem is not having your scheme shared, however I've checked this and it appears to be shared correctly.

I'm using the Xcode test for iOS step within my workflow. Another odd thing is running the build command locally works perfectly fine too.

Can anyone suggest any ideas for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 7):

> I'm getting an error message on Bitrise.io saying the scheme cannot be found within the project

It's not bitrise what prints this error, it's Xcode (Xcode's Command Line Tool, `xcodebuild`).

The most common cause of this issue is if you don't mark the scheme as shared. If you did, you should also check your gitignore list - shared schemes are have to be stored in the git repository, the related files can't be ignored!

Related docs: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/ios/frequent-ios-issues/#xcode-scheme-not-found - and related section:

**Don't forget to commit & push the changes** if you just enabled the Shared option!
This change should be reflected in your `git` repository,
under you project / workspace
(which is actually a directory, just seems like a file in Finder):
`*.xcodeproj OR *.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/xcschemes/SchemeName.xcscheme`.

If you still can't see the desired Scheme,
try to look into your `.gitignore` file and check if you are ignoring the config files of your Xcode project.

*This file have to exist after you do a clean git clone into a new directory on your Mac/PC.*

Comment: Dude, you made my day!

Comment: Glad I could help @Kowboj ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem for me by moving from xcode 8.2 to xcode 8.1.